# How to get average ratings in laravel using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have two table Users and ratings,.A User can give rating to consultant, My Rating table look like below

```
 User_id | consultant_id | rating
 ---------------------------------      
        1           1        2
 ---------------------------------
        2           1        3
 ---------------------------------
        3           1        1
 ---------------------------------
        4           1        1
```

This how my table looks like

My controller:

```
public function searchConsultants(Request $request)
{
         $location = $request->get('location');
         $data = Consultant::where('location','LIKE','%'.$location.'%')->with('ratings')->get();
         return response()->json($data);
}
```

Response Im get from searchConsultants method

```
[{"id":1,"cunsultant_name":"Manjunath Mj",
     "contact_number":"9035206471",
     "location":"Delhi",
     "department_id":1,09:00:51",

       "ratings":[{
           "id":1,"customer_id":1,"consultant_id":1,"rating":4, 
           "id":2,"customer_id":2,"consultant_id":1,"rating":2, 
           "id":3,"customer_id":3,"consultant_id":1,"rating":1, 
           "id":4,"customer_id":4,"consultant_id":1,"rating":5, 
    }]
}]
```

Im using ajax get method to diplay the data, here is my js file

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
   str +="<tr><td>"+data[index].id+"</td>
  <td>"+data[index].cunsultant_name+"</td>
  <td>"+data[index].contact_number+"</td>
  <td>"+data[index].ratings[index].rating_for_manager+"</td><td>"+data[index].location+"</td></tr>";
});
```

When I click search consultant button I should get consultant details with average ratings.

Comment: What is the specific problem and question? Take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: My problem is I need to calculate the average rating for particular consultant using above response that I'm getting from a query I've written and display.

Comment: Then explain that in full detail in the question. Also explain problems you are having achieving it. Again...read the above links thoroughly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the avg rating from the query in your Controller's searchConsultants method.

Change your query to this (this should give you average rating of each consultant matching with the search criteria):

> $data = Consultant::select('consultants.*', DB::raw('avg(rating)') )
>
> ->where('location','LIKE','%'.$location.'%')
>
> ->join('ratings', 'ratings. consultant_id', '=', 'consultants.id')
>
> ->groupBy('consultant_id')->get();

Comment: It says Unknown column 'rating.consultant_id' in 'on clause',could you please look into that

Comment: is spelling of column name "consultant_id" different in you table "ratings"?

Comment: No, there is no issue in spelling.

Comment: can you try executing below query in your db & check if this works or not:
"select avg(rating), consultants.* from consultants inner join ratings on consultants.id = ratings.consultant_id group by consultant_id;"

After that get the query from your code (by replacing ->get() with ->toSql() in your controller query ) & run that into your db.

Comment: yes it is working fine now how can I write that query in the controller ??could you please update the answer.

Comment: The laravel current code should work, just replace the "->get()" with "->toSql()" & echo $data ... this will echo the query & then try to find the different in this query from the one which is working.. if still not working then post me the query which echoed from your code

Comment: But when I write data[index].avg(rating) in jquery to display it does not show the data. You can check above jquery code for more information.

Comment: alias that "avg(rating)" to "avg_rating" in you'r controller  like: replace "DB::raw('avg(rating)') " with "DB::raw('avg(rating) as avg_rating ') " and then in you js use it like this: data[index].avg_rating